# Allow operations for daemon with custom context on different files with different context in SELinux

Tags: linux, redhat, fedora, selinux

## Special type of allow rule

I have created running daemon from executable file with custom context, something like:

```
system_u:system_r:daemon_name_t
```

It will traverse through entire directory recursively and read (not open) these unknown files (this files can have any context, not only from its domain), so i would like to write type enforcement rule with scontext `daemon_name_t` and *ANY* target context.
While writing type enforcement rule I would like it to stay as restrictive as possible. I don't want to give it context `unconfined_t`.

For example if I needed to allow operations `getattr` and `read` I would like get this effect:

```
allow daemon_name_t { * } :file { getattr read };
```

I can't find any possible way to do this with `SELinux`. Is this even possible? Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: i have found out that there is a way to enforce allow rule on file_type like this:

```
allow daemon_name_t file_type:{type1 type2} {getattr read};
```

It is sufficient for me for now, but it would be good to know if there is better solution.

Answer (score 2):

SELinux policy contains interfaces which simplify writing rules like this. The available interfaces are listed in [policy API documentation](http://oss.tresys.com/docs/refpolicy/api/) (the documentation should be provided by *selinux-policy-doc* package in your distribution). For example suitable interfaces could be [`files_list_non_auth_dirs`](http://oss.tresys.com/docs/refpolicy/api/kernel_files.html#link_files_list_non_auth_dirs) and [`files_read_non_auth_files`](http://oss.tresys.com/docs/refpolicy/api/kernel_files.html#link_files_read_non_auth_files):

```
files_list_non_auth_dirs(daemon_name_t)
files_read_non_auth_files(daemon_name_t)
```